# ソケット通信でif文が無視（スキップ）されてしまう

Tags: c, socket

ソケット通信を用いて複数プレイヤーのシンプルなゲームを作っています。
クライアントから送られてきた文字列をstrncmpで判別してそれぞれに適した処理が行われるようにしたいです。

例えば、”ADD 5"とクライアントから送られてきた場合に最初のADDを `strncmp` で判別して合計の数に５を足すようにしたいです。

しかし、どうしても `if` 文の処理が飛ばされてしまいます。色々と試した上でクライアントからサーバーへの文字列の送信は問題なく行われているので、`if` 文の部分に問題があるのは確かです。

クライアントからの処理が追いつかなくて `if` 文の処理が飛ばされしまうことなどはあるのでしょうか？何か解決策があれば教えていただけるとありがたいです。拙い文章で申し訳ありません。

サーバーサイド

```
  int sum = 0;
  int tmp;
  while (1)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_player; i++)
    {
      memset(client_buf, '\0', BUF_SIZE);
      
      if (recv(clientsock[i], client_buf, BUF_SIZE, 0) == -1)
        {
            perror("ERROR");
            exit(1);
        }  

      if(strncmp(client_buf, "ADD", 3) == 0)
      {
        strcpy(str, client_buf + 4);
        
        sum += temp;
      }
      // この後も他のelse if文が続く
　}
```

クライアントサイド

```
  while(1){
        memset(client_buf, '\0', sizeof(client_buf));
        if (recv(clientsock, server_reply, BUF_SIZE, 0) == -1)
        {
            perror("ERROR");
            exit(1);
        }  
        char str[BUF_SIZE]
        printf("Enter a number:");
        fgets(str, BUF_SIZE, stdin);
        sprintf(client_buf, "ADD %s", str);
        if (send(clientsock, client_buf, BUF_SIZE, 0) < 0){
             perror("Send failed");
        }
  }
```

Comment: 実際に受信したデータが何であるかを、if で判定する前にバッファ全体を16進数表記で表示するなりして確認してみてはどうでしょう？ 何か別のデータが頭に付いていたりするのでは？

Comment: こんな解説の動画 [今日のテーマ『C言語でチャットプログラムをつくる（UNIX / Linux）』](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2h0x4M4CHY) や記事とソースコード [Socket-chat-C](https://github.com/Masaki-Okuyama/Socket-chat-C), [ＴＣＰ／ＩＰネットワークプログラミング](http://onishi-lab.jp/programming/tcp_win.html) があるので参考にしてみてはどうでしょう？ 他にも探せば色々と見つかるでしょう。

Comment: `socket()` でどのような引数でディスクリプター作成したのでしょうか？ ストリームとデータグラムでは使い方異なるので, 質問を明確にしたほうがよいかも

Answer (score 2):

質問文には論理の飛躍が多々見られます。以下で説明しますが、具体的な事実に基づいて調査することをお勧めします。

---

> 色々と試した上でクライアントからサーバーへの文字列の送信は問題なく行われている

違います。クライアントが送信したこととサーバーが受信することは別問題です。あまり知られていないことですが、クライアントが送信した場合はクライアントが送信したことになるので、サーバーが受信したかどうかはサーバーが受信したかどうかで判断してください。（小泉構文）
例えば

> ```
> if (recv(clientsock[i], client_buf, BUF_SIZE, 0) == -1)
> ```

`recv()`は`-1`を返さなかったので受信エラーではないようですが、それではいったい何バイトのデータを受信したのでしょうか？ 受信エラーが発生していないことと期待するバイト数だけ受信が行われることは別問題です。このコードでは情報が読み捨てられていて判断できないです。

同様に

> ```
> if (send(clientsock, client_buf, BUF_SIZE, 0) < 0){
> ```

クライアントは送信に成功しているようですが、いったい何バイトのデータを送信したのでしょうか？ 「クライアントからサーバーへの文字列の送信は問題なく行われている」とありましたが、**送信できたバイト数を確認せずに**送信できたと判断するのは早計です。

> クライアントからの処理が追いつかなくて `if` 文の処理が飛ばされしまうことなどはあるのでしょうか？

そもそもサーバープログラムはどの行を実行しているのでしょうか？ 質問文にはそれがありません。 `if` 文の処理が実行されないことと `if` 文の処理が飛ばされることは別問題です。「飛ばされた」と判断するには「`if` 文の先にある処理が実行された」という情報が必要です。

Comment: 言葉足らずなところがあり、申し訳ありません。サーバー、クライアントの送受信を確認する部分を消して投稿してしまいました。私が行ったのはif文の前に受信した文字列をそのままprintfしましたが、問題なく正しく受信した文字列が表示されました。そしてwhileループの最後（if文の先）にサーバーとクライアント両方に”Turn end”と表示されるようにしていますがこれも問題なく動作しています。　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　もし何か改善案もしくはその他調査するべきことがあれば教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: @dondon コメントでなく、質問文を更新して質問文を完成させてください。また、確認できていること・できていないことをコードとともに示してください。

Comment: @dondon さん「改善案/その他調査/するべきこと」というのは、sayuri さんも書いているように、エビデンスの無い概要的なコメント・文章で応答するよりも具体的な内容と結果の詳細を質問記事に追記してください、ということです。例えば質問のコメントに書きましたが、単なる文字列としてprintfするのではなく、表示されない制御コード等があるかもしれないので16進数表記に変換して確認した方が良くて、その結果も質問記事に追記してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

> int sum = 0;
> int tmp;
> と変数定義がされていますが

> ```
>    sum += temp;
> ```

スペルミスという線は？